# Using FormcontrolName with label in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have angular 6 project with reactive forms. I have a grid like below. `Detail` button, open a modal window and showing student infos. My html of dialog is like below. But it gave me `No value accessor for form control with name: studentNumber` error. Is my html logic is wrong?

This not working

```
<form [formGroup]="studentForm">
  <p-dialog header="Student Detail" [(visible)]="displayStudentForm">
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Number</label>
        <label formControlName="studentNumber"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Age</label>
        <label formControlName="studentAge"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Type</label>
        <label formControlName="studentType"></label>
    </div>
  </p-dialog>
</form>
```

When I tried like below, working perfectly. But, this is very long for writing everywhere.

```
<label>{{studentForm.controls.studentNumber.value}}</label>
```

When I tried like below, working perfectly

```
<input formControlName="studentNumber">
```

[image: My grid]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To not repeat yourself I would create simple directive for that case:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, Optional, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: 'label[controlName]',
})
export class LabelControl {
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor(@Optional() private parent: ControlContainer) {}

  @HostBinding('textContent')
  get controlValue() {
    return this.parent ? this.parent.control.get(this.controlName).value : '';
  }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<label controlName="studentNumber"></label>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/qniUYzI9vjwvJM0NzPEh)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks @yurzui

Comment: I create your directive. But it didn't worked @yurzui. It gave me `Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: Can you provide simple demo on stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did misspelling (lowerCase letter). Your code worked perfectly. Thanks again @yurzui

Comment: Can be better if I rename "controlName" by "formControlName" or give problem in future. What do you think? Because, in angular using generally "formControlName"

Comment: If we rename it to formControlName then Angular built-in directive will break your code because you will have to implement custom ControlValueAccessor. But if you want more code is executed in your application then you can definitely do this. Here's an example https://ng-run.com/edit/xSPCiA4IjYvLXuIQGUY6

Comment: Thanks a lot @yurzui. I think this is perfect solution. In my opinion, can you change your answer by your second solution. It is much better from your first solution for looking for someone else.

Comment: @yurzui How do I set `formControlName` for a label so when I access `formGroup.value` then that label value should available in the JSON?

Answer (score 3):

IN component, you can create a getter method which will return form control value.

```
<form [formGroup]="studentForm">
  <p-dialog header="Student Detail" [(visible)]="displayStudentForm">
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Number</label>
        <label>{{getControlLabel('studentNumber')}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Age</label>
        <label>{{getControlLabel('studentAge')}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="p-grid">
        <label>Student Type</label>
        <label>{{getControlLabel('studentType')}}</label>
    </div>
  </p-dialog>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
getControlLabel(type: string){
 return studentForm.controls[type].value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SureshKumarAriya. But in real scenario, there will be 30 label not 3. And foreach, I will write get method. I don't know, Is this proper and recomended way? Because, I'm looking recomended way for this?

Comment: Or should I use template driven forms for doing this @SureshKumarAriya ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried before asking question. This is also working. But, my main question is; Is this job doing by this method in real world. Or any other best way? Because I used template driven forms and so I'm very inexperienced in reactive forms @SureshKumarAriya

Comment: You can follow the first approach (i.e getter method) if we have around 10 form control labels. In your case its 30 right. Its suggessted way to call component method which will return form control value based on input value. I have used this in many places in our application and its a recommended one. Template Driven Form approach is like Angular JS approach, we won't prefer that as Angular 2+ is modern web framework.

Comment: Thanks @SureshKumarAriya. Yurzui reply the question now. I think, it can be better. Is it true?

Comment: Thanks again @SureshKumarAriya